# Java Swing JFrame doesn't work in Ubuntu

Tags: java

I wrote the following program in Java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

However when I run it the icon shows up in the bar on the left, but no actual window is displayed. I use the `openjdk-8` at the moment, installed via `apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`. I also tried this with **Oracle Java** and it didn't work either.

How can I get my code to display a Frame?

Answer (score 0):

Java should work everywhere. Try to download a simple Java application from Internet too see if it works or not.

I think you need to set the position of your `JFrame`. Try
`frame.setLocation(x, y);`

Answer (score 0):

This run successfully on my ubuntu 20 with jdk-11.
[image: java]

Answer (score -1):

[This answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225144/java-setresizablefalse-changes-the-window-size-swing/21513649#21513649) by [mapadj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3263351/mapadj)

fixed mine:

> If you set setResizable false before setting the bounds, you will not have the problem. as Gergely Szilagyi stated before, you are getting rid of the scrollbars, but the size of the window is locked and therefore you end up with 9 or 10 pixels of extra space in the frame. I just had the same problem. thanks for the help.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.